# Angular / Firebase upload file Error: "[object Object]"

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-storage, angularfire2

**EDIT** : I found the solution needed to put the file name in the ref :

```
this.fireStorage.storage.ref(file.name).put(file);
```

I am trying to upload a file to FireStorage.
But I am stuck on this error:

> ERROR Error: "[object Object]"
>       Angular 13 GedInputComponent.html:6:2
>       View_GedInputComponent_0 GedInputComponent.html:6
>       Angular 13
>
> ERROR CONTEXT  Object { view: {…}, nodeIndex: 8, nodeDef: {…}, elDef:
>   {…}, elView: {…} } GedInputComponent.html:6:2
>       View_GedInputComponent_0 GedInputComponent.html:6
>       Angular 13

**Here is my code** :

```
<mat-dialog-content class="content">
  <input type="file" (change)="detectFile($event)"/>
</mat-dialog-content>
<mat-dialog-actions class="buttons">
  <button mat-raised-button (click)="addFile()">Add</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

Here I get the file :

```
export class GedInputComponent {
  selectedFile: File;

  addFile() {
    this.gedService.uploadFile(this.selectedFile);
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
  detectFile(event) {
    this.selectedFile = event.target.file;
  }
}
```

Here I try to upload the file :

```
export class GedService {
  constructor(private fireStorage: AngularFireStorage) { }
  public uploadFile(file: File): void {
    this.fireStorage.storage.ref().put(file); // When i remove this line there is no error
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you should do `this.selectedFile = event.target.file[0];`

Comment: I already tried this but it's not working. I have the same error unfortunatly

Comment: Did you see the correction @PierreDuc did to my answer? There was a typo. Thanks PierreDuc.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should do:

```
  detectFile(event) {
    this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
  }
```

Have a look at [Uploading files with upload](http://Uploading%20files%20with%20upload) and at [Using files from web applications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications).